# Selective extraction from patterned occurence (distant repeated lines) using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

A file has a line pattern where a line that does not contains  numbers occurs twice in the file.

```
Energy initial, next-to-last, final = 
 -87057.8200168321  -87208.7223900015  -87208.7197287879
Energy initial, next-to-last, final = 
 -87208.7197287879  -87208.7223900015  -87310.7197287879
```

I want to extract value `-87310.7197287879` which is the value at the end of the line following the 2nd occurrence of the line that does not contain numbers.

How can I do this with Awk or Sed ?

Comment: `awk 'END{print $NF}' file`?

Comment: please [edit] and add more of your given sample input when you are talking about _repeated lines _, otherwise for the given input I would simply suggest to use `awk 'NR%4==0 { print $NF }' infile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/^Energy initial, next-to-last, final =/ 
    { if (secondline==0) { secondline=1; next; } else { getline; print $3; } }' inputfile
```

-87310.7197287879

Comment: Thanks, I edited this with 
awk '/Energy/{ if (secondline==0) { secondline=1; next; } else { getline; print $3; } }' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in case you have such patterned occurrence happening once or more than once in your file:

```
$ awk '/^Energy initial, next-to-last, final =/ {a[NR]=1} 
       {if(NR >= 3 && a[NR-2] == a[NR] && a[NR] == 1) {toprint=1; next}}
       {if (toprint) {print $3; toprint=0}}' infile
```

No matter, Hauke's solution is far less ugly.

Answer (score -2):

Just a quicky:

```
> awk '{print $3}' /tmp/test.txt | grep -m1 -vE '[a-z]'
-87208.7197287879
```

The `awk` command prints the 3rd item (`$3`) from `/tmp/test.txt` and do a `grep` that does **NOT** match any letters (`[a-z]`) which eleminates the lines with text and stop after 1 selected lines (`-m1`)

Comment: No downvote from me. I guess you got the downvotes because the solution is exceptionally ugly.